# hyperlink message in twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to tweet a message with hyperlink to some website from my android application.
I am using twitter 4j api in my android app.

i.e. For example if i post a message "hello" in twitter, when i click hello it should redirect to some other website. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to create a tweet via twitter4j library from within an application you wrote. And this tweet should contain a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a hyperlink to a word in Twitter. It turns HTML into text. If you put http://yoursite.com as text into a tweet, it will be made a link automatically. But if you put <a href="http://yoursite.com">hello</a> into a tweet, the HTML will be displayed as text.

This is true on the site and through the API.